# HD cloning without deleted files

Tags: hard-drive, disk-cloning, acronis-trueimage

After cloning a HD, I analyzed target HD and found deleted files from source HD (files which i deleted long before the cloning!). So, do you know what settings in Acronis True Image prevent copying deleted files? Thank you.

Comment: are you using file or disk backup mode? file mode uses the disks file system, but disk mode does not. "deleted" is a file system concept, and matters at a very different level of abstraction than traditional imaging or cloning. they call them images or clones because they are bit-by-bit identical copies of the source. since the source disk or partition contains the "deleted" bits, they are part of the image. only the file system itself can tell what is or isn't "deleted", or even what is or isn't a file or other valid data structure.

Comment: I use disk backup mode so as to transfer the OS and drivers.

Comment: then I suggest using a free space wipe/secure deletion utility to zero or randomize the free space before imaging. that will remove all the offending bits before you clone the disk.

Comment: thanks. But it seems disk backup mode allows the user to choose whether to apply sector-by-sector and free space copy modes. if i unticked them, would deleted files be ignored during cloning?

Comment: sounds reasonable. I'd probably pick those names if I had to name those settings.

Comment: Yes; if you don't copy the free space you wouldn't copy the data that can be recovered in the free space